# HTML 5 Angular 10: Display array attribute values using EXL

Tags: html, angular, angular10

I'm trying to display user info using HTML and Angular 10, here my User Object:

```
    export interface User {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    userName: string;
    roles: Role[]; 
}
export interface Role {
    name: string; 
    
}
```

Here's my html code

```
            <tbody>
               <tr *ngFor="let user of users" >
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                <td>{{user.username}}</td>
                <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                <td>{{user.password}}</td>
                <td>{{user.roles}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
```

How can i get Role.names for every User separated by ",".

like:

```
  name  username    email               password    role
  user  adminName   admin@mail.com     admin123    ADMIN, MODERATOR, USER
```

Comment: İ didn't understand the question. Which format do you want to get?
{{user.roles.join('-')}} like that?

Comment: i want to get all roleNames for this user separated by ","

Comment: {{user.roles}} return an array for Role, i want to get the name for each one of this array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create separate function where you can get generated value for displaying

```
function getUserRoles(roles) {
  return roles.map((role) => role.name).join(‘ ,’)
}



<td>{{getUserRoles(user.roles)}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:

My way of doing this is another `*ngFor` at the end of the table, something like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users" >
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.username}}</td>
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    <td>{{user.password}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let role of user.roles">
      {{role.name}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

You have to use some CSS to properly display the last row and add a comma as well.

Comment: You mean <td *ngFor="let role of user.roles">
                    {{role.name}}
                  </td>

Comment: Oh yes, that's what I was thinking!